# Halcon - Gradient brightness

Tags: gradient, brightness, halcon

I have a image that is taken with uneven lighting.. there is a Light obove and one below the camera, so as a result, the image is properly lit in the center (top to bottom) but quite dark left and right.

Is there a way to apply a brightening filter with a gradient? so the more it nears the outer edge, the brighter it gets?

Solved with the answer from Mannari this way:

```
decompose3 (OriginalImage, ImageR, ImageG, ImageB)
trans_from_rgb(ImageR, ImageG, ImageB, ImageH, ImageL, ImageS, 'hls')

ImageWhite:=ImageL
gen_rectangle1(Rectangle,0,0,ImageHeight-1,ImageWidth-1)
* paint a white rectangle
paint_region(Rectangle,ImageWhite,ImageWhite,255.0,'fill')

tuple_real(BrightenWidth,BrightenWidth)
gen_image_gray_ramp (ImageGrayRampL, 0, -(255/BrightenWidth), 128, 1, BrightenWidth/2, ImageWidth, ImageHeight)
gen_image_gray_ramp (ImageGrayRampR, 0,  (255/BrightenWidth), 128, 1, ImageWidth-(BrightenWidth/2), ImageWidth, ImageHeight)
add_image (ImageGrayRampL,ImageGrayRampR,ImageGrayRampRaw,1,0)

mult_image (ImageL, ImageGrayRampRaw, ImageComp, 0.003, 0)


add_image (ImageL, ImageComp, BrightenedImageL, 1, 0)
add_image (ImageS, ImageComp, BrightenedImageS, 1, 0)
trans_to_rgb(ImageH,BrightenedImageL,BrightenedImageS,ImageR,ImageG,ImageB,'hls')
compose3(ImageR,ImageG,ImageB,CompensatedImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You can find an example in the demo multi_image.dev.

Here the demo code:

```
* This example demonstrates how to multiply two images using
* the operator 'mult_image'.
* 
* 
dev_close_window ()
dev_update_off ()
* 
* Read an input image and generate a second input image
* by creating a gray value ramp
read_image (Scene00, 'autobahn/scene_00')
gen_image_gray_ramp (ImageGrayRamp, 0.5, 0.5, 128, 256, 256, 512, 512)
* 
* Display the input images for the multiplication
dev_open_window_fit_image (Scene00, 0, 0, -1, -1, WindowHandle)
set_display_font (WindowHandle, 16, 'mono', 'true', 'false')
dev_display (Scene00)
disp_message (WindowHandle, 'Multiply the image with a gray value ramp', 'window', 12, 12, 'black', 'true')
disp_continue_message (WindowHandle, 'black', 'true')
stop ()
dev_display (ImageGrayRamp)
disp_message (WindowHandle, 'Created gray value ramp', 'window', 12, 12, 'black', 'true')
disp_continue_message (WindowHandle, 'black', 'true')
stop ()
* 
* Multiply the images with factor 0.005 for the gray value
* adaption and display the resulting image
mult_image (Scene00, ImageGrayRamp, ImageResult, 0.005, 0)
dev_display (ImageResult)
disp_message (WindowHandle, 'Resulting image of the product', 'window', 12, 12, 'black', 'true')
```

I think it's better if you grab a reference photo (for example with a white paper) instead of creating a gradient image.

Comment: Thank you very much! è proprio quello che cercavo!

Comment: Uhm, it looks like it works only for grayscale images... I do have a colored image.. I generated the gradient I need, and would like to brighten my colored image accordingly...

Comment: You can separate the RGB image in the three channels (gray images): red, green, and blue using decompose3. After you can process every gray image with the mult_image and finally you use compose3 to merge the three processed channels in a single RGB image.

Comment: thank you! it worked.. had to do it in HSL tough to have better results. increased brightness and saturation. I updated the main post with my working code.